# Keeping Toplevel above root after calling filedialog.askdirectory()

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have a root window and a Toplevel initialized, and I want the Toplevel to always be above root

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x150")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("test")
root.config(background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

def defaultFrameNoResize(geom, title):
    output = Toplevel()
    output.geometry(geom)
    output.resizable(0, 0)
    output.title(title)
    output.config(background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    return output

defaultsWindow = defaultFrameNoResize("500x150", "Change default settings")
```

And in `defaultsWindow` I have a button with the function:

```
lambda: text1Ptr.set(filedialog.askdirectory(
            initialdir=currentWorkspace
        ))
```

And when I press the button, the askdirectory interface comes up normally, but the root window goes above the Toplevel window.

I've tried using `defaultsWindow.lift()` and `root.wm_attributes("-topmost")` as well but to no avail

Thanks!

Comment: Add: `filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=currentWorkspace, parent=output)`

Comment: That worked, thanks!